# StartActivityForResult inside a library class in Android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I need to open the camera from the library class.This is the code below:

```
class LibraryClass extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void openCamera(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    } 
}
```

**I got this error:**

```
 cannot resolve method
 startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)
```

Can we not use startActivityForResult from inside a library?

EDIT 1 :

I had found [similar question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482342/start-activity-for-result-from-library), but could not get satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

try code

```
this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Hi Tai, it still gives error. Only option I get is to create a method startActivityForResult.

Comment: add Context in contructor of class
public LibraryClass(Context context)
{
}

Answer (score 1):

Is it your full code? It seems ok. You can invoke `startActivityForResult()` on any activity, so be sure when you are calling this method you are doing it on activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Context` as argument and then use it while starting new intent `context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

```
class LibraryClass extends AppCompatActivity{

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;


        // call by pass reference 
        openCamera(LibraryClass.this);

        public void openCamera(Context context){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        } 
    }
```